# Excel date-time auto fill error

Tags: time-series, pandas, excel

I have data of 10 metrics for a 24 hour period which is in 5 minute intervals. I merged all the 10 data metrics into one file and converted it into a .xlsx file.

After opening the excel file I created date-time column, filled 2 values and tried to fill the rest with Auto-fill option in excel. But the problem is after several rows the 5 minute interval changes to 4 minute interval,

Example:

```
18-11-2019 10:10
18-11-2019 10:15
```

If I try to auto-fill this data till the last column this is how the data changes,

```
18-11-2019 10:10
18-11-2019 10:15
18-11-2019 10:20
18-11-2019 10:25
.
.
.
18-11-2019 12:15
18-11-2019 12:19
18-11-2019 12:24
18-11-2019 12:29
```

When I click the `12:19` row, It shows `18-11-2019  12:19:59`.

It'd be helpful if someone explains why this problem occurs, and the solution?

Comment: Which version of excel are you using? Works fine with excel online.

Comment: Mine is Office 365, The problem is only with this particular file... I solved it the other way though, created a pandas date range and added to the excel file. Still looking for the solution in Excel